# するに not followed by motion verb

Tags: grammar, particle-に

All the questions I've seen are either using verb-には in place of verb-ために or verb-に followed by a motion verb. This seems to be neither.

Maruko's friend has just pulled a sweet out of his pocket. The narrator says:

> ピカピカ光るお洒落な包み紙から想像**するに**、缶に入っている物にちがいない。
>   From the shiny, stylish wrapping paper ??? it was certainly a thing in a can.

It might help to know that, earlier in the story, Maruko was obssessing over canned goods from hotels. In any case I can't figure out the meaning of this sentence. How do I understand 想像するに in this sentence?

Comment: I think this is a good question. Because we the native Japanese speakers, probably 99.9999% people don't pay any attention about the exact meaning of に when they use or speak it in our ordinary conversations.